# circulo com bordas shape

Tags: android, android-xml

Como fazer este circulo em xml ?

oque tenho até agora:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/corbtndia" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/corbtndia"/>
        </shape>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/vermelhoperfil"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Oque consegui:
[image: Oque quero]

Oque quero:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A imagem que postou é o que quer o é o que conseguiu?

Comment: @ramaral editei e coloquei oque quero e oque consegui

Comment: Não se enganou? Você quer uma ou duas bordas?

Comment: @ramaral acho que é uma borda só, porem ele tem uma parte para fora da borda, o problema é que eu nao consigo mudar a cor do jeito que fiz,pra ficar igual o dia 3 por exemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em meus projetos costumo a usar essa lib:

https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

**.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circleImageView1"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:src="#0A1950"
                app:civ_border_overlay="false" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circleImageView2"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="#0A1950"
                app:civ_border_color="#4D5B82"
                app:civ_border_overlay="false"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Day 1"
                android:textColor="#4D5B82" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circleImageView3"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:src="#0A1950"
                app:civ_border_overlay="false" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circleImageView4"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="#0A1950"
                app:civ_border_color="#4D5B82"
                app:civ_border_overlay="false"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Day 2"
                android:textColor="#4D5B82" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circleImageView5"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:src="#0A1950"
                app:civ_border_overlay="false" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circleImageView6"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="#0A1950"
                app:civ_border_color="#F44336"
                app:civ_border_overlay="false"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Day 3"
                android:textColor="#F44336" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circleImageView7"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:src="#0A1950"
                app:civ_border_overlay="false" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circleImageView8"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="#0A1950"
                app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
                app:civ_border_overlay="false"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Day 4"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tambem uso esta lib, porem não é oque preciso. ela tem uma unica borda, e como pode ver na imagem eu preciso de 2 bordas é diferente

Comment: só usar dois circle, um maior que o outro dentro de um RelativeLayout

Comment: o menor voce coloca borda

Comment: resposta editada.